# После входа в wordpress admin bar показывается только после ctrl + f5. Как сделать чтобы показывался сразу?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Нужно чтобы пользователю который вошёл на сайт сразу отображался admin bar - т.е. чтобы пользователь был сразу залогинен чтобы ему не нужно было дополнительно нажимать ctrl + f5.

Подскажите что можно сделать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Ничего не нужно перезагружать.. Ищи где поломал.

Comment: Выключить кеширование залогиненных пользователей.

Comment: Как вариант добавить reload после авторизации или же отключить кеш